# How to identify logical duplicates in a SQL table

Tags: sql-server

I am working in SQL Server 2008.  I have a very simple table which holds data for unit testing.  Let's call it table_A.  It has only 3 columns: col_1, col_2, and col_3  Because it's being used for unit testing, all 3 columns have data type varchar(255).  There are no primary keys defined, indexes, or any other constraints.

col_1 and col_2 comprise my natural key.  I want to determine if there are any duplicate natural keys in this table.  I know of at least one good technique for this.  That is the ROW_NUMBER, OVER, PARTITION BY, ORDER BY technique.  Another one that I'm not sure about is the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_A
WHERE
col_1 + ' ' + col_2
IN
(
SELECT
col_1 + ' ' + col_2
FROM table_A
GROUP BY col_1, col_2
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
)
```

Would this other technique return the same results as the ROW_NUMBER technique in every instance?  If so, would the performance be roughly the same as the ROW_NUMBER technique?

Comment: as to equivalence, yes they should be the same, as to performance why not try them both and see?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare the query plans for:

```
--Windowing Functions (faster)
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *
    ,c= COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY col_1,col_2)
  FROM MyTable
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE c > 1;

--Inner Join (slower)
SELECT t1.*
FROM MyTable t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    col_1
   ,col_2
  FROM MyTable
  GROUP BY col_1,col_2
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
ON (
      t1.col_1 = t2.col_1 
  AND t1.col_2 = t2.col_2
);

--Corellated Subquery (slower)
SELECT t1.*
FROM MyTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM MyTable t2
  WHERE t1.col_1 = t2.col_1 
    AND t1.col_2 = t2.col_2
  GROUP BY col_1,col_2
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

**Don't use key concatenation.**  It can't distinguish between these two rows:

```
INSERT MyTable
  (col_1,col_2)
VALUES
  ('a b','c'  )
 ,('a'  ,'b c')
```

In both rows, `col_1 + ' ' + col_2 = 'a b c'`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible solution which also can use indexes:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM table_A a
WHERE EXISTS 
  (
      SELECT b.col_1, b.col_2 
      FROM table_A b 
      WHERE a.col_1 = b.col_1 and a.col_2=b.col_2 
      GROUP BY b.col_1, b.col_2 
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
   )
```

Comment: Doesn't the EXISTS clause slow down the query?http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php

Comment: That article is very misleading. What they write in the note is **not true**, at least not in in this case! _["...the sub-query is RE-RUN for EVERY row in the outer query's table..."]_ **Look at the execution plan:** The outer and the inner select are execute ONCE, then they are joined. **The performance is good.** SQL server does in general a very good job at optimizing.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding the performance:**

In this case you use the "+" operator for creating an artifical field, which then is used for a lookup.

This method is definitively slowing down the query, since indexes cannot be looked up, and the optimizer cannot work at best. It's always better to stick with more set-oriented methods. Without exactly knowing your other solution, a usage of OVER and PARTION BY sounds already very good.

Comment: There's a well-known `NOT IN`-problem based on three-valued logic, but what is this `IN`-problem you're talking about?

Comment: @dnoeth That's very right, I'm a little tired already. Deleted the part. To be continued at another time ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col_1, col_2 ORDER BY col_1) As rn
    Table_A ) a
WHERE
     a > 1
```